# jQuery UI Chosen MultiSelect plugin selection retained in Chrome but not IE11 or Edge

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-chosen

I had a question directly opposite to [the next one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16852380/6677992):

I'm using the jQuery [ChosenMultiSelect](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plugin. When using `IE 11` or `Microsoft Edge`, if I select 3 options from the dropdown, browse to another page and then press the browser back button, the values are not retained in the textarea.

In Chrome if I do the same thing the values are retained.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this works by setting parameters in the URL by `window.history.pushState (null, null, url);`.

Function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39664620/6677992):

```
function parameterizeArray(key, arr) {
    if (!arr) {
        return "";
    }
    arr = arr.map(encodeURIComponent);
    return '?' + key + '=' + arr.join('&' + key + '=');
}
```